# Android Seekbar Progress Color at runtime

Tags: java, android, background, seekbar

I want to change the seekbar progress color and background color at runtime with code not with xml. I know how to do it with xml`(Layerlist-Shapedrawable-Clipdrawable)`
I can't change the colors in my `colors.xml` so I  have to set the progress drawable by code.
I already tried different things with LayerDrawable etc... but didn't get anything to work.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

```
public void setProgressBarColor(ProgressBar progressBar, int newColor){ 
    LayerDrawable ld = (LayerDrawable) progressBar.getProgressDrawable();
    ClipDrawable d1 = (ClipDrawable) ld.findDrawableByLayerId(R.id.progressshape);
    d1.setColorFilter(newColor, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);

}
```

When you update the progress, you will see the result.

Is it ok?

Comment: Thanks for the answer but that isnt exactly what i was looking for.
Tried this already but the problem is I'm using a gradient with start,center and end color as progress. ColorFilter changes the whole Progressbar progress to one single color.